# Date Format incorrect in Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a Date Time field in a report with format set to *31/01/2000 13:30. It says on the dialog that Formats that begin with an asterisk (*) will reflect the regional settings of the report.

It also confirms below that my current regional settings are: English (UK)

I then deploy to my local report server and run the report and it displays in American Date format e.g. 01/31/2009.

The local report server is set to run under my own local account which is set to UK format regional settinsg.

Where is it picking up these American settings from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In BIDS or ReportBuilder *NOT in the SSRS website*, select "Report" in the properties window and set the language:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to set different language as default? It's cumbersome to always change it from american format.

Comment: Or you can put Language "=User!Language", then it takes it from your Windows settings